# Java - Jsoup HTTP Error Fetching URL

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup/java to access google news articles based on the subject a user types in. When I try to access the google news webpage however, I get a run time error from this line:

```
try {
doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q="+ "technology").get();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

When I execute this code I get this error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=technology
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
at newsbot.NewsBot.onUpdateReceived(NewsBot.java:93)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.BotSession$HandlerThread.run(BotSession.java:197)
```

However, if I type the  [link](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=technology) into google, the webpage I want to acess apears perfectly. I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you add -Djavax.net.debug=all to see detailed logs.  That should help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the user agent:

```
Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q="+ "technology")
     .userAgent("blah-blah")
     .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a user agent , that way the page will not be forbidden (HTTP 403)

```
Document doc = (Document) Jsoup
                .connect("https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=" + "technology")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
        System.out.println(doc);
```